# what does SAP HANA's := syntax do?

Tags: sql

I was looking at some SAP HANA stored procedures and I saw some expressions like this:

```
declare str nvarchar(50);
str := N'test';
```

As far as I can see, `str = N'test';` works just fine, what exactly does the `:=` operator do?

Comment: `:=`is assignment. (As in many languages.)

Comment: `=` is already assignment. why another one? any differences?

Answer (score 0):

It is an assignment for a variable.